# Apache 2.4 RewriteRule only working with domain name

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, centos7

I'm moving an old site from apache 2.2 to 2.4

I've got a `vhost.conf` file that contains the following rewriterule:

```
RewriteRule ^/news/[0-9]{4}/[A-za-z]{3}/([0-9a-zA-Z-]*)/([0-9]{4})([0-9]{6})/?$ "/news/article.cfm?article_id=$3&urltitle=$1&clk=$2" [NE,L]
```

So I'm trying to turn this url:
https://example.com/news/2016/Feb/Article-Title/0025012345

into this:
https://example.com/news/article.cfm?article_id=012345&urltitle=Article-Title&clk=0025

Depending on what I put in the 2nd part of the RewriteRule I get the following:

`"https://example.com/news/article.cfm?article_id=$3&urltitle=$1&clk=$2"` this works fine but I don't  want to specify the hostname as it gets used on dev/staging/live servers, so the URLs change

`"/news/article.cfm?article_id=$3&urltitle=$1&clk=$2"` this throws a 404 which shows up in the `access_log`

`"news/article.cfm?article_id=$3&urltitle=$1&clk=$2"` this throws a 503 which shows up in the `access_log`

So I know I'm correctly identifying the URL in the first part of the rule and grabbing the correct components with my regex, as specifying the full domain name shows the correct URL manipulation.

I'm completely failing to do a relative redirect though, and I'm certain this rule works in Apache 2.2

I'm using the following software:

CentOS Linux release 7.7.1908 (Core)

Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
Server built:   Aug  8 2019 11:41:18

Answer (score 0):

Obviosuly, the answer is in the manual... which I should have read in more detail:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html#old-to-new

> Assume we have recently renamed the page foo.html to bar.html and now want to provide the old URL for backward compatibility. However, we want that users of the old URL even not recognize that the pages was renamed - that is, **we don't want the address to change in their browser.**

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule    "^/foo\.html$"  "/bar.html" [PT]
```

The key thing here being the `[PT]`, that fixed it for me:

```
RewriteRule ^/news/[0-9]{4}/[A-za-z]{3}/([0-9a-zA-Z-]*)/([0-9]{4})([0-9]{6})/?$ "/news/article.cfm?article_id=$3&urltitle=$1&clk=$2" [PT,NE,L]
```